# How do you pipe an observable on the view to an observable on the view model using ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveTableViewController backed by a ReactiveList. I'd like the ElementSelected observable on ReactiveTableViewSource to push the selected/touched row/object to an observable on my view model so I can use all the fun LINQ operators with it. Specifically my scenario is that the tableView starts with "parent" cells and when an item is touched, I want to insert multiple "nested" cells below it, all driven by the view model.

Whats the "Right way" to get an observable on the view model giving me the row selected? I know creating my own subjects and whatnot is overkill, but I'm new at ReactiveUI and not sure what the correct mechanism to use would be.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Paulcbetts:

Pass the ElementSelected observable into the ViewModel's constructor. That way during a test, you could pass a dummy observable in.